# Good way to resolve dependencies for .rpm installation

Tags: linux, package-management, rpm, installation-package

I am trying to install `jdk-7u25-linux-x64.rpm` through rpm. However, rpm says it conflicts with `jre-1.6.0_13-fcs`. I then try to remove `jre-1.6.0_13-fcs` but it fails because there are other packages that depend on it.

Is there a better way than for me to remove all possible dependencies and then re-install them back after I successfully install `jdk-7u25-linux-x64.rpm`?

Answer (score 0):

i cant comment on jre / jdk specifically, but yum shell can do what you want.

yum shell:

`remove jre
install jdk
run`

will swap one for the other, if all dependencies are met. I've done this previously to switch out syslog-ng with rsyslog.

Comment: sudo yum remove jre also removed all my dependencies.

Comment: now I have to re-install them back after I installed jdk. :-(

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said I couldn't speak for jre/jdk. I've never needed to do what you're trying here, which suggests to me that there's a better way than swapping one for another. Off the top of my head I don't know enough java fu to advise though